# Depth function that counts number of nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I'm looking for a function that gives the depth of nested lists in an expression. I do not want to include contributions from things like `f[1]`. Depth does do this. Note `Depth[{f}] != Depth[{f[1]}]`. Does this exist or does someone have a good function for this.

---

My attempt:

```
depth := Depth[# //. f_[__] /; ! f === List -> f] &
```

but I'm sure someone more experienced can do better. (I'm probably forgetting many cases where this would not give the desired result.)

Comment: What about lists inside other heads? Could you give couple of examples and desired results?

Comment: @Kuba, Yes well spotted. For the current thing I'm using it for I don't have lists inside arguments, so I'm safe. I guess it's not that clear what the desired result would be in that instance (which also explains why such a function is not included in Mathematica). Both the option of excluding and including these lists in the count seem like a valid option and an interesting function. Excluding these is more likely to be what I might need in the near future. I guess I'd accept either (or the best would be both) as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to count lists in the arguments, you can use the following recursive definition:

```
ClearAll[depth];
depth[{}] := 2;
depth[list_List] := 1 + Max[Map[depth, list]];
depth[_] := 1;
```

Testing:

```
depth[{f}]
```

> 2

```
depth[{f[a]}]
```

> 2

```
depth[{f[{a}]}]
```

> 2

```
depth[{f[a], {{f[b]}}}]
```

> 4